# Node.js mongo Invalid modifier specified: $set undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using Node.js + Express to interact with mongodb.

I am trying to write a mongodb update function wrapper.

whenever I make a post request mongo reports "Invalid modifier specified: $set undefined".

Anyone know what's wrong with my funciton wrapper? or is there a better way to do this?

my update_personal_info.js looks like this:

```
exports.update_personal_info = function(req, res){
var critia = req.body.critia;
var data = req.body.data;
db.collection('accounts', function(err, collection) {
    collection.update(critia, data, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("There's problem updating the db");
        }
    });
});
}
```

The post data I am using to send via Chrome's extension "Advance Rest Client":

```
critia={"_id": "user_1234"}
data={$set: {"password": "44444444"}}
```

my app.js looks like this:

```
app.post('/1',update_personal_info);
```

accounts collection looks like this:

```
{
"_id": "user_1234", 
"name": "John Chu", 
"password": "111111", 
"address": [
    {"old": "123 seattle st. WA. 123456"},
    {"new": "123 new york st. DC. 123456"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping $set in quotes: data={"$set": {"password": "44444444"}}

Comment: Ok, I've tried it and it still reporting "Mongo Error: Invalid modifier specified: $set undefined"

Comment: @HectorCorrea: the [error message is misleading](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12546). `$set` doesn't need quotes; rather, whatever was passed to `$set` is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem by convert the post data string into an object using the eval() function:

```
var critia = eval("("+req.body.critia+")");
var data = eval("("+req.body.data+")");
```

Hope this answer will help others.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Using `express 3.4.4` and `mongodb 1.3.20` it works just fine when I run it.  Are you using a really old version of the mongodb driver?

One thing to me sure you are doing is setting the Content Type correctly in the Advanced REST Client.  If you are using the Form tab in the Payload section, you need to set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

**Some general guidance:** 
You don't want to have the client send in the selector and the document. It opens you up to allow someone to send in values that could do some damage to your data.

Comment: Hi Joe, Running the code is fine, but when submit data via the Advanced REST Client it reports error. I'm currently using Express 3.4.4, and mongodb 2.4.8. As for the Advanced REST Client, I did use application/x-www-form-urlencoded setting. Thanks for the security concern, It's only accessible from the internal network so should be fine for now I guess :)

Comment: Hmm, not sure then.  I used the Advanced REST Client to test it out and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I've tried to specified the you've mentioned, and the error code is different this time:
Error: selector must be a valid JavaScript object:undefined

any ideas?